# Readmore arrow - hover effect - slide in text

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I've a container with an arrow on the bottom. On hover I want that the arrow animates to the right when the readmore (lees meer) text slides in.

State 1: http://postimg.org/image/5ovuxrfdd/ 
(readmore text is invisible, overflow:hidden)

State 2: http://postimg.org/image/y5imixrbd/

I already have this working with some CSS animation BUT I use fixed pixels on the transform property. I also want this to work responsively. So I need a more dynamic approach.

I hope I can solve this without JS.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
.button {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
text-decoration: none;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover .readmore {
   transform: translate(0,0);
  margin-left: 0;
}

.readmore {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    margin-left: -20px;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

.arrow {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    top: -2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nkfv9n6y/3/